# How to boot back to Ubuntu within Windows by editing the Grub file when Grub Customizer is installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu OS. Currently, Windows is the default OS. Within the Ubuntu environment, I use the Grub Customizer to change the order of OS. I have Linux File Systems for Windows by Paragon to read/write the Ubuntu partition. I went through multiple online solutions to change the Grub configuration file, but none of them worked in my case where Grub Customizer has been installed. Under Windows in the `grub` file, I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to  `GRUB_DEFAULT=1`, where `0` and `1` are the order of Windows and Ubuntu. But this did not boot back to Ubuntu. I noticed changing the order in the Grub Customizer did not change the `GRUB_DEFAULT` value in `/etc/default/grub` file.

How can I change back to Ubuntu from Windows by editing the Grub file when Grub Customizer is installed in Ubuntu? Below are the `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` files:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`grub.cfg` file:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode



### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###
menuentry "Windows" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-82B9-41CD' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  82B9-41CD
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 82B9-41CD
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-97-generic root=UUID=6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-97-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/33_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/36_linux_proxy ###
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-97-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-97-generic-advanced-6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-97-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-97-generic root=UUID=6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-97-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-97-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-97-generic-recovery-6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-97-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-97-generic root=UUID=6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-97-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-96-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-96-generic-advanced-6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-96-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic root=UUID=6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-96-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-96-generic-recovery-6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-96-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic root=UUID=6bf5eb39-ee48-4b45-a2a7-38c91f2da948 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/36_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/37_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/37_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/38_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/38_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/39_os-prober_proxy ###


set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/39_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/42_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/42_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/43_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/43_custom ###
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, use a live cd, it might be easier.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity could you please elaborate on how to use live cd?

Comment: [Here's a guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) on how to create a bootable usb with a live system. Then you boot your computer from the usb. Once in the OS you'll have access to all the drives an their files.